# Set a default scratch buffer

Tags: init-file, major-mode, scratch-buffer

My emacs daemon for ocaml (I use more than one emacs daemon) starts in a tuareg scratch buffer.  I am aware of `initial-major-mode` but this hasn't worked: the scratch is started before `(setq`initial-major-mode 'tuareg-mode)` is evaluated.

Since I keep the `initial-buffer-choice` to scratch, I just run `(tuareg-mode)` and my scratch mode is modified as I want.

But now, when I kill the scratch, new scratch buffers are not in tuareg mode, so I added a little hack found on stackexchange:

```
(defun prepare-scratch-for-kill ()
  (save-excursion
    (set-buffer (get-buffer-create "*scratch*"))
    (tuareg-mode)
    (add-hook 'kill-buffer-query-functions 'kill-scratch-buffer t)))

(defun kill-scratch-buffer ()
  (let (kill-buffer-query-functions)
    (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
  ;; no way, *scratch* shall live
  (prepare-scratch-for-kill)
  ;; Since we "killed" it, don't let caller try too
  nil)

(prepare-scratch-for-kill)
```

It works, but now I don't see my magnificent `initial-scratch-message`.
I have tried to `(setq initial-major-mode 'tuareg-mode)`, which normally modifies the scratch major mode.  But it doesn't, even if I start a new scratch.

I would like to do it the proper way, emacs embeded way, but what I have tried doesn't work.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, one thing that you should make sure of is that `tuareg-mode` is loaded before you set `initial-major-mode`. I originally followed the instructions here to do what you want to do, http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/07/25/configure-the-scratch-buffers-mode/ but it sounds like you have already tried these steps

Comment: All right it was as simple as that !
Thank you !

Comment: @elethan Since it seems to have answered the question, can you convert this comment into an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto could you provide a few details about what you changed in your configuration to get things to work the way you wanted? If I haven't mentioned it in my answer already, then I can include those details for future readers. Thanks!

Comment: Sure !
I install and configure packages with the package (this sound like an inception xD) use-package. It's good because it can help yout emacs init faster by loading mode only when it's needed  instead of loading all modes at startup which can takes so times.
The suggestion of elethan is that maybe my mode wasn't loaded before setting it  as the scratch default mode, so the line before `(setq initial-major-mode 'tuareg-mode)` i've added `(require 'tuareg)` and it works !
Thank you elethan !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My original suggestion to the OP based on my own slightly misguided experimentation was this:

make sure that the mode you want to set as the `initial-major-mode` is loaded before you set `initial-major-mode` with `(setq initial-major-mode 'name-of-mode)`. This seems to have solved the problem that the OP was having.

However, I have also tested changing my entire `init.el` to contain only the lines:

```
(setq initial-major-mode 'tuareg-mode)
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
```

and literally nothing else, and when I started emacs I got a `*scratch*` buffer in `tuareg-mode`.

This leads me to believe that something else was causing the issue, but I am happy that my suggestion could lead to a solution one way or another. Also, in my case `tuareg-mode`was installed through `MELPA` and would have automatically been added to the `load-path`, which might not have been the case for the OP, and this could be why I have no issue with the above configuration.

[Emacs Redux](http://emacsredux.com/) also has [this short, useful tutorial](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/07/25/configure-the-scratch-buffers-mode/) on how to solve the problem in question.

In general, I think setting `initial-major-mode` as described above in your `~/.emacs` or `init.el` or whatever emacs config you use should be enough to set a default mode for your scratch buffer.

However, if you find that this doesn't work as was the case for the OP, it won't hurt to ensure that `initial-major-mode` is set to the desired mode *after* the package that contains that mode gets initialized. If setting `initial-major-mode` *still* doesn't work as expected, you can follow the advice in [this accepted answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14062/8430) and check that the value has not been set in `customize` with `M-x customize-option RET initial-major-mode RET`. From here you can not only see what value this variable has been set to, but also change the value.